# Add related list in map

Tags: soql, map, related-list

I have a custom object which has a related list. I want to store it in a form of `Map<Id,List<related_list>>`.

I am able to query related list but it's format change as I am querying it using relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with Account and Contacts (based on query on Parent object using sub-query and relationship name):

```
 Map<Id, List<Contact>> mapAccountWithContacts = new Map<Id, List<Contact>();

 for(Account objAccount: [SELECT Id, Name, 
      (SELECT Id, LastName From Contacts) FROM Account]) {
      mapAccountWithContacts.put(objAccount.Id, objAccount.Contacts);
 }
```

Example if you want to simply query form it by querying child records:

```
Map<Id, List<Contact>> mapAccountWithContacts = new Map<Id, List<Contact>();

 for(Contact objContact: [SELECT Id, LastName, AccountId From Contact 
      WHERE AccountId != null]) {
      if(!mapAccountWithContacts.containsKey(objContact.AccountId)) {
           mapAccountWithContacts.put(objContact.AccountId, new List<Contact>());
      }
      mapAccountWithContacts.get(objContact.AccountId).add(objContact);
 }
```